# Add custom schedule to AWS ec2 lifecycle manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

How can I use cron expression to schedule quarterly backup? Like Backup at 12:00AM on every 1st January, 1st April, 1st July and 1st October.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up the event with this:

```
cron(0 12 1 1/3 ? *)
```

This translates to:

`1/3` -> every third month

`1` -> on the first day of the month

`0 12` at 12 PM

One of the day-of-month or day-of-week values must be a question mark `(?)`

PS. Keep in mind that time is in `UTC+0`.

[More on Scheduled Expressions in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html)

Comment: Thanks for comment. */3 is not work. But can I use 1/3?

Comment: Yes, 1/3 works in Lifecycle manager but */3 works with eventbridge.